# Dynamic choice fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Referencing the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) on this, I have set up the following:

```
Category_Choices = (
    ('Food', (
        ('burger', 'hamburger'),
        ('pizza', 'pizza'),
        ),
    ('Drink', (
        ('soda', 'soda'),
        ('water', 'water'),
        ('milk', 'milk'),
        ('beer', 'beer'),
        ),
    ('Dessert' , (
        ('ic', 'ice cream'),
        ('pie', 'pie'),
        ('cake', 'cake'),
        ),
)
```

I understand referencing an initial tuple:

```
choice = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Category_Choices)
```

But how do I limit that to just Food?  If I have one choice list where a user selects only Food, Drink, or Dessert, how do I limit a second choice list to only Food item, or only drink items, etc?  The Django docs don't cover that part.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the linked documentation yields this response:

> "But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn’t change much, if ever."

The choices field is not intended to give dynamic behavior, ie display only certain subsets of choices.

My suggestion would be to create another model object to accommodate just the Food list.

Comment: I didn't think this was hacking it _too_ much, but perhaps you are right.  Any idea how I'd restrict a second choice list in a form based on the first choice?  Or is that just asking too much?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: For restricting the choice list based on the first choice - Django doesn't come with that behavior.  I wrote my own hacky jquery to do it when I needed it, but I've also seen people use this project: https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects